# Swift Generic Functions, Protocols and associatedType - Cannot invoke function with an argument list of type '(from: T)'

Tags: swift, generics, protocols, keypaths

I am trying to generalise a functions for different types of objects that does the same things (retrieves a value from the objects using a keyPath).

```
class GenericOutputParameter<Type>: Equatable    {

    // Single Line Parameter for the Deal parameters


    var path: WritableKeyPathApplicator<Type>
    var label: String
    var value: Any?         // THIS IS OPTIONAL
    var format: Int
    var columnID: String
    var order: Int

    init(path: WritableKeyPathApplicator<Type>, label: String, value: Any?, format: Int, order: Int, columnID: String)  {

        self.path = path
        self.label = label
        self.value = value
        self.format = format
        self.order = order
        self.columnID = columnID
    }
 }

protocol haveOutputs {

    associatedtype containerType

    var dictionary: [String : (path: WritableKeyPathApplicator<containerType>,label: String, value: Any, format: Int, order: Int)] { get set }
    var outputs: [GenericOutputParameter<containerType>] { get set }

    }



func fillOutputs<T: haveOutputs>(container: inout T)   {

    container.outputs.removeAll()

    for (columnID, valueTuple) in container.dictionary {

        container.outputs.append(GenericOutputParameter(path: valueTuple.path, label: valueTuple.label, value: valueTuple.path.retrieve(from: container), format: valueTuple.format,order: valueTuple.order, columnID: columnID))
        }


    container.outputs.sort(by: { $0.order < $1.order })

    }   // END OF FILLOUTPUTS
```

I am using associatedType in the protocol as each object  has its own different dictionary.

The function fillOutputs(container: inout T) retrieves the value from the object  for the parameter specified by the key paths and appends it to an array.

I am getting an error in the container.outputs.append line towards the end of the code, as follows: Cannot invoke 'retrieve' with an argument list of type '(from: T)'. This refers to retrieve(from: container).  Before attempting to generalise, this function was a method of each object (container) and using retrieve(from: self) worked.

For reference, the retrieve method is part of another generic function:

```
class WritableKeyPathApplicator<Type> {

    private let applicator: (Type, Any) -> Type
    private let retriever: (Type) -> Any

    init<ValueType>(_ keyPath: WritableKeyPath<Type, ValueType>) {

        applicator = {

            ...

            }


        retriever = {
            ...

            }

        }


    func apply(value: Any, to: Type) -> Type {
        return applicator(to, value)
        }


    func retrieve(from: Type)   -> Any  {
        return retriever(from)
        }

}
```

Given I am not an expert on Swift nor fully comprehend protocols, I may have lost myself in a glass of water and I would appreciate any thought/help.  Thanks

Comment: This feels wildly overcomplicated, but I'm having trouble working out the goal. Relying on `Any` is almost certainly wrong. Coupling that with generics and a protocol with associated type (PAT) is definitely way too much. "retrieves a value from the objects using a keyPath" is just `object[keyPath: keyPath]`, so what is this really trying to do? What does the calling code look like? What algorithm makes use of this protocol?

Comment: Rob - Thanks for taking the time.  At the heart of this is a table which represents an array of objects.  The objects' properties are in the columns of the table. The object has a lot of different properties (about 100) of different types (String, Int, Double, etc). Each property has a different column Name associated and is represented in a different format and color. The Object references a dictionary which stores the properties used by GenericOutputParameter.

Comment: So far it would be simple. But there are more tables, representing different objects belonging to different classes, with different parameters.  Hence the need for generic functions that handle the representation of each property in the same way, regardless of the class it belongs to.  The key paths are to different parameters for different types of objects.  I hope this clears your question.

Comment: Have you written a working system for one (smallish) table? Start there, including (most importantly!) the calling code. How would something use this? What kinds of algorithms can work on this data structure? (The fact that you're returning Any means you've almost certainly broken your calling code.) Then build a second table. From there, extract what is common. Almost certainly what you want here is a simple (non-associatedtype) protocol to put into an Array. You might then wind up adding some other protocols (with associatedtypes) to help share code.

Comment: But the most important thing here is that you must get rid of `Any`. That's breaking this whole system, and I don't think you're going to be able to work around it. Again, working from the calling code, and ensuring you do not require `as?`, will push you in the right direction. If you'll give an example of how you would like to call this code and use the results (something that does not include `as?`), then I can probably help you design the right data structure to allow that. For example, will this tie to a tableview?